# Is there a meaningful way to combine relative and absolute difference?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, group-differences

I have two datasets for two different scenarios in the same study area.

To clarify, it is the origin and destination of trips - split up in different zones. Therefore zone 1 has x-many origins and y-many destinations. It differs though by scenario. 
For some zones, the difference is from 10 to 9, whereas others change from 1000 to 999 and others again from 1000 to 500.

Is there a meaningful way to unite absolute and relative difference, or does it make more sense to remain with either of these measures?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is measured? What are the units?

Comment: the unit trips. Per zone, it is measured how many trips originate in the zone, and how many end in the zone.